# Main Window closes after execvp() call

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am learning QT and QT Creator to have experience in working with it. Using Arch Linux with the latest QT libraries.

On a button click function, I am trying to do the following:

```
std::string name= filename.toStdString();
char *file_path = (char*)name.c_str();

char *myargs[] = {"wormhole", "send", file_path, NULL};
int rc = execvp(myargs[0], myargs); /*This call is the question*/
```

At the point where the `int rc` declaration occurs, the mainwindow spawned by this class closes. I am not sure why. Perhaps `execvp()` is not the right call to make to run the other program?

This call would pass a full file path as an argument to wormhole, it could either exist in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin, hense the call to `execvp()`

Comment: Perhaps `execvp` is not the right call to achieve what? What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: @idclev I am trying to call another program passing in a file name as a c-string argument. It does succeed and print to stdout but I no longer have the main window.

Comment: what is the name of the file and the path? Please include that information in the question

Comment: That has nothing to do with my question when execvp() actually runs the other program.

Comment: if it has nothing to do with the question then why is that the question? " Perhaps execvp() is not the right call to make?" ...

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `execvp`? What in "The exec() family of functions **replaces** the current process image with a new process image." is unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current process is being replaced by the new instantiated process.

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.

[Execvp Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp)

You probably would want to fork() first, then use execvp().

Comment: I totally forgot to use `fork()` in this case and then I would use the child proc to execute another program. It now works perfectly!